# Can i customize html and css in $page[content] in drupal 7?

Tags: html, css, templates, drupal-7

when i write the code for the page template like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <?php print render($page['header']) ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <?php print render($page['content']) ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-wrapper">
        <?php print render($page['footer']) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

like the question above is there any way to change the html and css of $page[content]?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the development environment, checkout the generated html code. There should be some file suggestions. These are different templates, Drupal tries to execute. The one marked with '*' is the one used. Yo can overwrite any more specific file.